# Python doubling some backslashes while leaving others

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am defining the following string in python:

```
s = '(?<=\n\d{8})(.*?)(?=\n\d{8})'
```

When I `print` it, python returns:

```
'(?<=\n\\d{8})(.*?)(?=\n\\d{8})'
```

Why it is doubling the backslash before the d?

I have also tried to make the string raw:

```
s = r'(?<=\n\d{8})(.*?)(?=\n\d{8})'
```

and in this case, python `print` output is:

```
'(?<=\\n\\d{8})(.*?)(?=\\n\\d{8})'
```

What is the reason behind both of these behaviours?

Comment: If you print it with `print(s)` that's not the output you'll get

Comment: Yeah but why just the second backslash? and not both n and d

Comment: Because if you put unescaped `\n` in a string literal, you don't get a ```\``` followed by `n`; you get the newline character `\n`. Whereas in the version where you use a raw-string literal, you actually get ```\``` followed by `n`, so the backslash is doubled in the repr.

Comment: you can write it as response and I will accept